# how to make a foreach loop for more array than 1

Tags: php

I need to insert a mass load of data from 4 different arrays into my database, but I can't figure out how to make a foreach loop for this.

This is a shortened vesion of my script (don't mind the unfinished query).

code:

```
$latitudeArray = array(
    array('latitude'=>'52.37124908')
);

$longtitudeArray = array(
    array('longtitude'=>'4.893587136')
);

$bodyArray = array(
    array('body'=>'Waterplastiek: een halfronde vorm met treden waaruit water stroomt naar een in de bestrating uitgeholde granieten goot.')
);

$titleArray = array(
    array('title'=>'ReNESsance-fontein (Nes 45, op plein voor Vlaams Cultureel Centrum, Theater De Brakke Grond)')
);

$mysqli = new MySQLi("localhost", "root", "", "po");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ({$mysqli->connect_errno}) {$mysqli->connect_error}";
}
// The first part of the SQL query
$query = "INSERT INTO `markers` (`name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `type`, `desc`) VALUES (``,``,``,``,``,``)";

// This is the format of a VALUES tuple; it is used
// below in sprintf()
$format = " ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %f, %f),";

// Go over each array item and append it to the SQL query
foreach(array_combine($titleArray,$bodyArray,$latitudeArray) as ) {
    $query .= sprintf(
        $format,
        $mysqli->escape_string($price['PriceDate']),
        $mysqli->escape_string($price['Fund']),
        $mysqli->escape_string($price['Currency']),
        $mysqli->escape_string($price['Class']),
        $mysqli->escape_string($price['NAV']),
        $mysqli->escape_string($price['NavChange'])
    );
}
// The last VALUES tuple has a trailing comma which will cause
// problems, so let us remove it
$query = rtrim($query, ',');

// MySQLi::query returns boolean for INSERT
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if ($result == false) {
    die("The query did not work: {$mysqli->error}");
} else {
    die("The query was a success!");
}
```

Comment: If all of those four arrays are related to each other, you should have them in a SINGLE array, e.g. `$data=array(array('lat' => ..., 'long' => ..., ....))` so they're logically grouped together.

Comment: Well that was something that I considered to do, but being as it may that I got more than 100 different entries, this would take really long time to do. So I'm looking for an alternative, if there is any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the answer you were looking for, but you should just use a for loop instead

```
$A=array(3,4,2,3,4,4,5,5,6);
$B=array(3,4,2,3,4,4,5,5,6);
$C=array(3,4,2,3,4,4,5,5,6);

for ($i=0;$i<count($A);$i++)
    $query.= $A[$i].' '.$B[$i].' '.$C[$i];
```

Something along those lines.  Foreach can also handle an index but the result will be more confusing.